# Essential strumming patterns/techniques? and the theory behind it?

Tags: guitar, theory, chord-theory, fingering, strumming

I used to play silly led zeppelin and velvet underground covers. i knew all the vu strumming just because i knew the records by heart. i've started to get more into classic folk and country and nick drake stuff.

is there a good list of strumming patterns/techniques or video because none of the resources on google have really helped me so much

edit: i'd also really like to understand more of the theory behind finger picking too, a bit more than basic progressions and stuff, like why would i choose to play something like that, if that makes sense... if anyone can recommend another book or link

i have some old folk books from the 50s and 60s (and 00s), they teach how to play the classics with basic picking patterns but don't really extrapolate

Comment: Try "chicken pickin'", "travis picking" and "clawhammer style" on youtube.

Comment: ^ that is pretty useful but im looking for more in depth picking/strumming lessons. i got my hands full at the moment with stuff to practice. guess i'd just like more opinions on finger picking. theres a big difference between a faceless kid playing a solid folk cover on youtube vs robert johnson. maybe that comes down to life experiences and stuff but i feel there must be a book or link that makes more sense of it all....if that makes sense